# Redux Toolkit with TypeScript - typing RootState with an SSR framework like Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

The [the official Redux Toolkit docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) recommend typing the `RootState` as follows:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
  },
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

However, when using Redux with server-side rendering (SSR) framework like Gatsby, I need to export my configureStore call as a callable function, so I can be sure it is only instantiated once:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

// 'store' is recommended by the gatsby team to be a function,
// See https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-redux/wrap-with-provider.js
export const store = () => configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
  },
})

// TODO: won't work because store is not a const anymore, it is a function!
// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
// export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
// export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

anybody know how I can reconcile keeping the configure store call a function (to follow Gatsby best practices), yet still getting the `RootState` type out somehow (so I can use things like `useSelector` throughout my app)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold on to your hats for this one:

```
type ConfiguredStore = ReturnType<typeof store>;
type StoreGetState = ConfiguredStore["getState"];
export type RootState = ReturnType<StoreGetState>;
export type AppDispatch = ConfiguredStore["dispatch"];
```

As a side note, I'd suggest naming that function `makeStore` or something like that, rather than just calling it `store`.

Comment: Excellent! It works! I've modified your code to export the two exports needed in the app, `RootState` and `AppDispatch`. I forgot that for completeness we should include the `AppDispatch` type as well, following the Redux Toolkit recommendations.